# about align text to the center's css

Tags: css

[image]

[my web's URL](http://www.ecotw.com.tw/vicky/hl-doc/)

How to move the words in green frame into the red frame?  I set up my css but
it doesn't change, where is the problem?

Where is the problem? and how to fix it??
Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

```
html code:
          <div class="topmenu">
              <a type="button" class="btn btn-flat text-white">儲存</a>               
              <a type="button" class="btn btn-flat text-white">陳核</a>   
              <a type="button" class="btn btn-flat text-white">退文</a>   
              <a type="button" class="btn btn-flat text-white">決行</a>   
              <a type="button" class="btn btn-flat text-white">關閉</a>   
          </div>
```

css code:
.topmenu {
text-align:center !important; }

Comment: should copy all html with your sample it is centered

Comment: It's unclear what your intention is and how it's not working as intended. Please provide more context.

Comment: How to move the words in green frame into the red frame?  I set up my css but it doesn't change, where is the problem?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `text-align: center !important` won't work due to the fact that your element is **not covering the whole navbar so it is centered already**.

### `width: 100%;` solution

So you should **make your `div` maximize to its available space** with `width: 100%;` and then use `text-align: center;` so the output should be something like this:

```css
.topmenu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**NOTE:** It won't perfectly work if you add extra elements to your navbar.

### Margin auto solution

The other approach to achieve this is to **force the div to have a specific space with their adjacents** by using `margin: 0 auto;`. like this one:

```css
.topmenu {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**NOTE:** Since **you got an empty div in the left side of the nav elements** `<div class="search-form d-none d-lg-inline-block"></div>`, this may look weird in the first place, but whenever you delete that empty `div` or try to import your search input within it you will see the results and would be working perfectly.

Comment: I made it !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you very much.
you've saved my life, I can't thank you enough. T_T

Comment: I am using ipad to browse, these menu still show on the right, can't be centered, what is the reason and how to solve this? I hope these will be centered no matter what device is used.

Comment: @VickyLee This is because you are using two different classes for wide and small screens, so just add `.topmenu-mobile{margin: 0 auto;}` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Width of your div is adapted to its content and pulled to right.

Try to do this in your css,

css code: .topmenu { text-align:center !important; width:100%;}

[image]

Comment: I did try your suggestion but the green frame section still cannot be centered.

Comment: Take a look, I added an image. Added width:100% in browser, it works.

Answer (score 0):

When going to the URL you provided and opening the DevTools, I can see that you have

```
<div class="navbar-right">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">...</ul>
</div>
```

If you provide more samples of the code you're using, we can direct you better on what changes you need to make.

Comment: I used firefox browser then press F12, this should be
equal to  your DevTools.  I used this to check but I still failed in the setting.

Not quite familiar with this stack overflow sequence, can you tell me what info you can provide, really sorry for my ignorance.

Topmenu's HTML code should be above <div class="navbar-right"> , not 
beneath <div class="navbar-right">, I have no idea why it's still on the right side.

How do you insert code under comment? Can you teach me? thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but in case you want to set your list in center vertically, you can use **flexbox**

```
.topmenu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Learn more about [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: May be I did  not make it clear enough.  What I meant is I forcefully set
the menu Through css to be centered, but still come as the right side, I could not find out the reason why. http://www.ecotw.com.tw/vicky/hl-doc/